# Your file system in '/usr/local/GCC-ARM-Linux-GNUeabi/.build' is *not* case-sensitive

Tags: macos, gcc, arm

This is making absolutely no sense to me: I just installed crosstool-ng and I need to install the gcc-arm-linux cross-compiler toolkit on my mac. I used `ct-ng arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi` and it worked fine. Next step was `ct-ng build`, which I followed. It resulted, however, in this error.

```
Your file system in '/usr/local/GCC-ARM-Linux-GNUeabi/.build' is *not* case-sensitive!
```

I am lost and it's imperative that I install the toolkit in order to cross-compile for a Linux-based micro-controller for a project I'm in.

Comment: Well, it's true, HFS+ is not case-sensitive.

Comment: Is there something I can do in order to work around that?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix it by partitioning the disk, creating a small space that was case-sensitive. Basically, I followed [this tutorial](http://www.benmont.com/tech/crosscompiler.html). This problem and some subsequent ones I was able to fix. However a wild new problem appeared. But that is the subject of [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238752/build-failed-in-step-top-level).